# The capacity to get research funding, how to explain my reply?

Tags: application, postdocs, funding

I am going to apply for a research position. There are several questions in the formula that I have to fill up. One is "The capacity to get research funding".  I do not understand what I have to write as an answer for this sentence. Is it enough to put the  previous fundings that I got? A couple of years ago, after my Phd I was awarded a research grant. Do I need to explain anything special about them? Or just list them. They asked this question along with some other questions under the title "Selection Criteria".
Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do with your answer is to make the case that you will most likely get grants in the future, if you were to be hired.

That you have been successful with a grant application in the past tends to be the best factual basis for such a claim. However, your narrative should be forward-looking. Is the grant you got similar to those grants you'd be applying for in that position? If not, how will you adapt? Do you have other good ideas for grants? Are you aware of the relevant funding bodies?

I'd expect this question to be one of the most important ones, if not ***the*** most important one. The amount of detail you give compared to other questions should probably reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to know how much detail they require unless you ask them. Assuming you have a history of successful funding, just ask how much detail they want beyond a list of past success.

A few words about the relevance of your research to potential funding organizations would probably be wise to add in any case.